# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null in laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Actually, I am using autocomplete in my input from where data comes from `enrolCourse` table if I see my route data return from database table my it does not show in my form show this error. I am uploading my form code and javascript code

```html
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/enrollCourse/store')) !!}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"></div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/saveResult/create')) !!}
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Student Register','Search Student Register Number')}}
                        {!! Form::text('reg_id', null, array('id'=>'reg_id','placeholder' => 'Search Registration Number','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close()  !!}
                <div class="col-md-7">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Student Registration','Student Registration Number')}}
                        {!! Form::text('reg_number', null, array('id'=>'reg_number','placeholder' => ' Registration Number','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Name','Student Name')}}
                        {!! Form::text('s_name', null, array('id'=>'s_name','placeholder' => 'Enter Student Name','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Email','Student Email')}}
                        {!! Form::email('email', null, array('id'=>'email','placeholder' => 'Enter Student Email','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Department','Department ')}}
                        {!! Form::text('department_id', null, array('id'=>'department_id','placeholder' => 'Enter Student Department','class' => 'form-control','onchange'=>"teacherQuery() ")) !!}
                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Select Course','Select Course ')}}
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <select name="course_id" class="form-control" id="course_id">
                            <option value=" ">----Select Course-----</option>
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('Select Grade','Select Grade ')}}
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <select name="grade_id" class="form-control" id="grade_id">
                            <option value=" ">----Select Course-----</option>
                            <option>A+</option>
                            <option>A</option>
                            <option>A-</option>
                            <option>B+</option>
                            <option>B</option>
                            <option>B-</option>
                            <option>C+</option>
                            <option>C</option>
                            <option>C-</option>
                            <option>D+</option>
                            <option>D</option>
                            <option>D-</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        {{Form::submit('Enroll',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}


@endsection
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dropdown = "<option value=''>----Select Course-----</option>";
        $('#reg_id').autocomplete({
            source: '{!!URL::route('autocomplete/result')!!}',
            minlenght: 1,
            autoFocus: true,
            select: function (e, ui) {
                $('#reg_number').val(ui.item.reg_num);
                $('#s_name').val(ui.item.s_name);
                $('#email').val(ui.item.email);
                $('#department_id').val(ui.item.department_name);
                for(var i=0;i<ui.item.course_id.length;i++){
                    dropdown +="<option value='"+ui.item.course_id[i].id+"'>"+ui.item.course_id[i].name+"</option>"
                }
                $('#course_id').html(dropdown);
                console.log(ui);
            }
        });



    </script>
@endsection
```

and Controller code here

```html
public function  autocompleteResult(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->term;
    $date = EnrollCourses::where('reg_num','LIKE','%' .$term. '%')->with('course')->take(10)->get();

    $result = array();
    foreach($date as $key=> $v)
    {
        $result = ['reg_num' =>$v->reg_num,'s_name'=>$v->s_name, 'email'=>$v->email,'department_id'=>$v->department_id, 'course_id'=>$v->course['name']];
    }
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

I need your help guys please suggest me, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you proper installed Laravel collective and added the Form Alias to your `config/app.php`?  
Why you closing the form after the first group? Why do you use `{{csrf_field()}}` a couple of times within the same form? You need it only once per form and if you open a form via `Form::open()`, you don't need it at all. Please fix your code and see if this already helped.

Comment: You seem to be opening a form within a form?  Pretty sure that's not possible.  Also you've used `csrf_field()` twice, not needed.

Comment: The form is null because you close the form before you use `Form::label`

Comment: Acutely I have a little bit confused about csrf_field(). if I use lara collective form then do not need to use csrf_field().

Comment: I have removed {{csrf_field()}} but return the same error .

Comment: I think `$v->course` might be null, so attempting `$v->course['name']` will resulting an error. And shouldn't it be `$v->course->name`? Please provide your Model too

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SaveStudentResult extends Model
{
    //
    public function course()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Course','id','course_id');
    }
}